# Run only modified test files gulp.

Tags: gulp, karma-runner

I am using karma and gulp-karma with angularjs,

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
/// Be sure to return the stream
return gulp.src(config.paths.karmaTest.src)
.pipe(karma({
  configFile: './karma.conf.js',
  action: 'run'
}))
.on('error', function(err) {
  // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
  console.log(err)
  this.emit('end');
  //throw err;
});
});
```

This works but it is too slow is there a way create a watch and run only the modified tests ?

Comment: How would you know if your modifications in source code break other tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well maybe you can watch for your spec files and then pass the path of modified file to karma so it run only this file. If you need other files to run your tests, you will have to declare them into the `files` parameter of *karma* with `e.path`, otherwise it won't work.

Basically you can do something like this:

```
var karma = require('karma').server;

gulp.task('watch-test', function (done) {

  gulp.watch('tests/**.spec.js', function (e) {

    karma.start({
      configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
      files: [e.path],
      singleRun: true
    });

  });

});
```